# Does a wait on Scala Future block thread?

Tags: scala, actor, future, promise

When I **wait** for result of Scala Future, does it behave more like **receive**, or like **react**, i.e. does it block a thread, or schedules a continuation after result if available?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, in stdlib it blocks the thread, and synchronously waits for results. If you want to apply continuation-passing style to futures, you'd have to use Akka or Scalaz that allow adding hooks on futures completion straight from the box.

[Akka](http://doc.akka.io/futures-scala):

```
val f1 = Future { Thread.sleep(1000); "Hello" + "World" }

val f2 = f1 map { _.length }

f2 foreach println //Done asynchronously and non-blocking
```

Same with [Scalaz](http://code.google.com/p/scalaz/):

```
scala> val f1 = promise {Thread.sleep(1000); "Hello" + "World"}
f1: scalaz.concurrent.Promise[java.lang.String] = scalaz.concurrent.Promise$$anon$1@1f7480

scala> val f2 = f1 map{str => str.length}
f2: scalaz.concurrent.Promise[Int] = scalaz.concurrent.Promise$$anon$1@1d40442

scala> f2.map(println)
10
res5: scalaz.concurrent.Promise[Unit] = scalaz.concurrent.Promise$$anon$1@116ad20
```

Answer (score 1):

It should block current thread, but whether the worker thread is blocked, it depends.