# Is there a standard Scala function for running a block with a timeout?

Tags: scala, concurrency

I need to call into a service that may or not return timely results. I'd like to be able to write

```
val result = runWithTimeout(5000, valReturnedOnTimeout) { service.fetch }
```

Is there a standard function that will do the job - like Ruby's [timeout](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/index.html)?

Comment: And yes I know that using Actors would solve this, but it seems overkill for such a simple problem.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/q/5797666/132374

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With credit to the other answers - in the absence of any standard library function, I've gone down the Futures route.

```
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
  import scala.concurrent._
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  def runWithTimeout[T](timeoutMs: Long)(f: => T) : Option[T] = {
    Some(Await.result(Future(f), timeoutMs milliseconds))
  }

  def runWithTimeout[T](timeoutMs: Long, default: T)(f: => T) : T = {
    runWithTimeout(timeoutMs)(f).getOrElse(default)
  }
```

So that

```
  @Test def test {
    runWithTimeout(50) { "result" } should equal (Some("result"))
    runWithTimeout(50) { Thread.sleep(100); "result" } should equal (None)
    runWithTimeout(50, "no result") { "result" } should equal ("result")
    runWithTimeout(50, "no result") { Thread.sleep(100); "result" } should equal("no result")
  }
```

I'd be grateful for any feedback as to whether this is a good Scala style!

Comment: I've extended this to deal with exceptions at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229778

Comment: this solution does not seem to work at least with scala 2.12

Comment: Would be better to have a FiniteDuration as argument, as opposed to forcing the user to measure in ms.

Answer (score 5):

You could use a future

```
import scala.actors.Futures._  

val myfuture = 
    future {
     Thread.sleep(5000)
     println("<future>")
     "future "
 }

 awaitAll(300,myfuture ) foreach println _
```

But also have a look at [Circuit Breaker for Scala](https://github.com/FaKod/Circuit-Breaker-for-Scala/wiki/) which is a implementation of the 
[Circuit Breaker Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern). Basically it lets you control the timeout and what should happen if a failure occurs accessing an external resource

Usage looks like this in Scala (from the readme) :

```
. . .
addCircuitBreaker("test", CircuitBreakerConfiguration(timeout=100,failureThreshold=10))
. . .


class Test extends UsingCircuitBreaker {
  def myMethodWorkingFine = {
    withCircuitBreaker("test") {
      . . .
    }
  }

  def myMethodDoingWrong = {
    withCircuitBreaker("test") {
      require(false,"FUBAR!!!")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the circuit breakers, but I guess that there's nothing in the standard library. I'll try writing something based on the Futures to keep it simple.

Comment: note that the future blocks the thread. http://stackoverflow.com/q/5646879/203968 So a client that calls you many times might end up starving your threads. Hence the circuit breaker. where you could "break the circuit" when you think the call will not probably work

Comment: Yes, I'm going to have to consider that, as the calls are in my web layer and so I can have one per browser. I may have to have the browser poll and use Executors in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Might [Futures](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/actors/Futures%24.html) and its `alarm` do the trick?

Comment: I hadn't seen that, thank you, and it's certainly a way of implementing the function - if it doesn't already exist.

Answer (score 2):

Something that hasn't been mentioned yet is **awaitEither**, a method on the actors package's Futures object. awaitEither returns the result from the first of a pair of futures to complete, so for example something like this could be used:

```
awaitEither(future{task}, alarm(timeoutPeriod))
```

and then dressed up in a method as suggested:

```
def runWithTimeout[T](timeoutPeriod: Int, timeoutValue: T)(task: => T) = {
  awaitEither(future{task}, alarm(timeoutPeriod)) match {case () => timeoutValue case x => x}
}
```

**alarm** returns Unit which is assignable to a val of type Any so awaitEither returns something that can be pattern matched against.

Comment: I considered that when @pr1001 pointed out `alarm` but thought that we'd probably end up starting another thread for alarm - which seemed a bit overkill. It does make for a nice short expression though.

Answer (score 1):

You can start it in a new Thread and then wait for it to finish with Thread.join. If you pass a parameter to join, it waits at most that many milliseconds.

```
val t = new Thread {
  override def run() {
    //...
  }
}
t.start()
t.join(5000)
```

Comment: Thank you, and I could also use the Executors framework. But I was checking that I wasn't missing something built-in or idiomatic.

Answer (score 0):

The post above

```
  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global   import
 scala.concurrent._   import scala.concurrent.duration._

   def runWithTimeout[T](timeoutMs: Long)(f: => T) : Option[T] = {
     Await.result(Future(f), timeoutMs milliseconds).asInstanceOf[Option[T]]   }

   def runWithTimeout[T](timeoutMs: Long, default: T)(f: => T) : T = {
     runWithTimeout(timeoutMs)(f).getOrElse(default)   }
```

didn't work for me on Scala 2.11.

Following modified version works for me:

```
  def runWithTimeout[T](timeout: Long)(f: => T): Option[T] = {
    Option.apply(Await.result(Future(f), timeout seconds))
  }
```