# How do I get hold of exceptions thrown in a Scala Future?

Tags: scala, exception, concurrency, actor

I've been working up my answer to [Is there a standard Scala function for running a block with a timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6227759/97777), and have run into a problem if an exception is thrown in a Future.

```
  def runWithTimeout[T](timeoutMs: Long)(f: => T) : Option[T] = {
    awaitAll(timeoutMs, future(f)).head.asInstanceOf[Option[T]]
  }
```

So that

```
runWithTimeout(50) { "result" } should equal (Some("result"))
runWithTimeout(50) { Thread.sleep(100); "result" } should equal (None)
```

But if I throw an exception in my block it doesn't leak, but is swallowed - so that the following fails with "..no exception was thrown"

```
intercept[Exception] {
    runWithTimeout(50) { throw new Exception("deliberate") }
}.getMessage should equal("deliberate")
```

Syserr has a stack trace with the message

```
<function0>: caught java.lang.Exception: deliberate
```

but I can't find where in the Scala runtime that is printed.

Apart from wrapping f in another block which catches exceptions and propagates them if thrown, is there any way to persuade awaitAll and/or Future to throw?

Comment: It is probably printed because it got passed to the thread's [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html). You could set your own handler, but that would still not allow you to throw the exception in a different thread.

Comment: Have a look at Fingales futures (https://github.com/twitter/finagle), search for "Timeout" and Akka http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.2/scala/futures.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Exceptions don't do what you want when you're working in a threaded context, because you want to know about the exception in the caller, and the exception happens in the future's thread.

Instead, if you want to know what the exception was, you should return an `Either[Exception,WhatYouWant]`--of course, you have to catch that exception within the future and package it up.

```
scala> scala.actors.Futures.future{
  try { Right("fail".toInt) } catch { case e: Exception => Left(e) }
}
res0: scala.actors.Future[Product with Serializable with Either[Exception,Int]] = <function0>

scala> res0()   // Apply the future
res1: Product with Serializable with Either[Exception,Int] =
      Left(java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "fail")
```

Comment: Java's `Future.get()` throws `ExecutionException`, in which it wraps any Exception in the executing code. That was my model here.

Comment: @Duncan McGregor - I don't know how Java accomplishes it, but if it's done as a library there isn't much choice but to have the thread take the exception, package it, and deal with it on the other end.  My guess is that Java does it for you since it doesn't have any general mechanism to allow this; Scala has you do it yourself (using the general mechanism supplied for such things).

Comment: I've accepted this answer as most helpful and provided an implementation as my own answer. Note that @Vikto Klang gives the simplest solution, but not for the standard Scala Future.

Comment: You can use Try instead of Either

Answer (score 10):

Disclaimer: I work for Typesafe

Or.... you could use [Akka](http://akka.io/docs/akka/1.1.2/scala/futures.html) and it would give you what you want without you having to go through hoops for it.

```
val f: Future[Int] = actor !!! message
```

Then

```
    f.get
```

Will throw the exception that happened in the actor

```
    f.await.exception
```

will give you an Option[Throwable]

Comment: Good to know that I wasn't so off-base thinking that it should be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Working my way through @Rex Kerr's suggestion, I've created

```
object Timeout {

  val timeoutException = new TimeoutException

  def runWithTimeout[T](timeoutMs: Long)(f: => T) : Either[Throwable, T] = {
    runWithTimeoutIgnoreExceptions(timeoutMs)(exceptionOrResult(f)) match {
      case Some(x) => x
      case None => Left(timeoutException)
    }
  }

  def runWithTimeout[T](timeoutMs: Long, default: T)(f: => T) : Either[Throwable, T] = {
    val defaultAsEither: Either[Throwable, T] = Right(default)
    runWithTimeoutIgnoreExceptions(timeoutMs, defaultAsEither)(exceptionOrResult(f))
  }

  def runWithTimeoutIgnoreExceptions[T](timeoutMs: Long)(f: => T) : Option[T] = {
    awaitAll(timeoutMs, future(f)).head.asInstanceOf[Option[T]]
  }

  def runWithTimeoutIgnoreExceptions[T](timeoutMs: Long, default: T)(f: => T) : T = {
    runWithTimeoutIgnoreExceptions(timeoutMs)(f).getOrElse(default)
  }

  private def exceptionOrResult[T](f: => T): Either[Throwable, T] = 
    try { 
      Right(f) 
    } catch { 
      case x => Left(x)
    }
}
```

so that

```
  @Test def test_exception {
    runWithTimeout(50) { "result" }.right.get should be ("result")
    runWithTimeout(50) { throw new Exception("deliberate") }.left.get.getMessage should be ("deliberate")
    runWithTimeout(50) { Thread.sleep(100); "result" }.left.get should be (Timeout.timeoutException)

    runWithTimeout(50, "no result") { "result" }.right.get should be ("result")
    runWithTimeout(50, "no result") { throw new Exception("deliberate") }.left.get.getMessage should be ("deliberate")
    runWithTimeout(50, "no result") { Thread.sleep(100); "result" }.right.get should be ("no result")

}
```

Again, I'm a bit of a Scala novice, so would welcome feedback.

Answer (score 2):

`scala.concurrent.ops.future` includes exception handling.

So, instead of importing `scala.actors.Futures.future`, import `scala.concurrent.ops.future instead`.

That simple change in which import is there will cause the caller's call to .get to rethrow the exception.  It works great!

Comment: Seems that `scala.concurrent.ops.future` was removed in Scala 2.11 and therefore this answer does not apply anymore: https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/67d7e26657a0a52e2bd5dc46bd1bbedda52d2dc0#L4L41

Answer (score 0):

Or use `Future.liftTryTry`, turns it from `Future[Object]` to `Future[Try[Object]]`, and you can match on the `Try[Object]` and check for an exception `case Throw(e)` and log / exit gracefully

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the method `exceptionHandler` in order to catch exceptions. So your option is to define your own `future` method so it creates a MyFutureActor with exceptionHandler.

EDIT: FutureActor is private, so subclassing it isn't possible.

Another option is to use links to know when exceptions happened.

However, I think Rex Kerr's approach is better - just wrap the function in something that will catch the Exception. Too bad `future` doesn't already do that.

Comment: I liked the sound of this, but FutureActor is private and complicated enough that reproducing it would be hairy.