# In Scala, does Futures.awaitAll terminate the thread on timeout?

Tags: scala, concurrency, jvm, akka

So I'm writing a mini timeout library in scala, it looks very similar to the code here: [How do I get hold of exceptions thrown in a Scala Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229778/how-do-i-get-hold-of-exceptions-thrown-in-a-scala-future)

The function I execute is either going to complete successfully, or block forever, so I need to make sure that on a timeout the executing thread is cancelled.

Thus my question is: **On a timeout, does awaitAll terminate the underlying actor, or just let it keep running forever?**

One alternative that I'm considering is to use the java Future library to do this as there is an explicit cancel() method one can call.

Comment: What do you mean by "block forever" &ndash; is that blocking I/O? Maybe use asynchronous I/O instead. Hard interrupting a Java thread is not a recommended thing. Otherwise, if the block is still 'receiving', why not use an actor approach as in the answer of Viktor Klang given in the question to which you link? Then you could send an abortion message to that actor.

Answer (score 0):

[Disclaimer - I'm new to Scala actors myself]
As I read it, `scala.actors.Futures.awaitAll` waits until the list of futures are all resolved OR until the timeout.  It will not `Future.cancel`, `Thread.interrupt`, or otherwise attempt to terminate a `Future`; you get to come back later and wait some more.

The `Future.cancel` may be suitable, however be aware that your code may need to participate in effecting the `cancel` operation - it doesn't necessarily come for free.  `Future.cancel` cancels a task that is scheduled, but not yet started.  It interrupts a running thread [setting a flag that can be checked]... which may or may not acknowledge the interrupt.  Review `Thread.interrupt` and `Thread.isInterrupted()`.  Your long-running task would normally check to see if it's being interrupted (your code), and self-terminate.  Various methods (i.e. `Thread.sleep`, `Object.wait` and others) respond to the interrupt by throwing `InterruptedException`.  You need to review & understand that mechanism to ensure your code will meet your needs within those constraints.  See [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html).