# Throwing exception from a scala.concurrent.Future

Tags: scala, future

I was trying to reproduce this issue [How do I get hold of exceptions thrown in a Scala Future?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229778/how-do-i-get-hold-of-exceptions-thrown-in-a-scala-future) using `scala.concurrent.Future` and I was expecting the exception to be swallowed but it doesn't seem to happen. Any explanation?

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def runWithTimeout[T](timeoutMs: Long)(f: => Future[T]) : T = {
  Await.result(f, timeoutMs.millis)
}

runWithTimeout(50) { Future { "result" } }

runWithTimeout(50) { Future { throw new Exception("deliberate") } }
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Futures do **not** swallow exceptions (at least not in the usual sense, which means "catch and discard"). When you throw an exception in a future (either in the body of `map`/`flatMap` or when using `Future.apply`), the exception indeed is not propagated into the current thread, but it is preserved in the future and becomes the future's result. Indeed a future's eventual result is a `Try[T]`, so it will be completed either with a proper result of type `T` (a `Success[T]`), **or** with a `Throwable` (`Failure[T]`).

Another key point is that when you call `Await.result` you are basically asking to block the current thread by waiting on the eventual result of the future, be it a proper result **or an exception**. In the case of an exception, it will be rethrown at the point where `Await.result` is called.
If you don't want the exception to be rethrown, you can use `Await.ready` instead. It will wait for the future's completion and just return the future itself, whether it completed normally or through an exception. Then you can retrieve the future's result via `Future.value`

Comment: ah! this is so nice! thanks for the very clear explanation