# Scala try/catch vs recover different handing exception in future

Tags: scala, exception, error-handling

What is the difference between

```
try {
       Future . map { }

} catch {}
```

and

```
Future.map {} recover {}
```

Are they not the same thing? How does a try catch handle exceptions in futures vs how the recover method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229778/how-do-i-get-hold-of-exceptions-thrown-in-a-scala-future

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you are using a `Future`, you are wrapping a result inside it, hence the exceptions are wrapped as well.

That's why this code doesn't print anything:

```
try { Future(throw new RuntimeException(""))} catch { case ex => println("Got it") }
```

While this code prints "Got it":

```
Future(throw new RuntimeException("")).recover { case ex => println("Got it") }
```

`recover` and `recoverWith` methods helps you to handle the wrapped exceptiion (if any).

Comment: Thank you very much sir, this is a clear and simple explanation

Comment: Will recover and recoverWith also be able to handle raw Exceptions and not wrapped one?

Comment: No, When you use a function returning `Future[T]`, it's a bad practice to throw exceptions outside of the `Future`. You'd need a try/catch for those.