# Set a timeout for a scala method

Tags: scala, future

I am trying to set a timeout for a method. I have the following code inside a test. The return value of `f` is a special type I have defined. It returns `Interval(Int, Int)`.

```
val f = evalfunc (a, b)
```

The evalfunc is using an external simplex solver. Sometimes it gets stuck here. I want to set a timeout for this. I have tried Future timeout following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227759/is-there-a-standard-scala-function-for-running-a-block-with-a-timeout/6228910).

```
def runWithTimeout[T](timeout: Long)(f: => T) : Option[T] = {
 Await.result(Future(f), timeout seconds).asInstanceOf[Option[T]] }
```

`def runWithTimeout[T](timeout: Long, default: T)(f: => T) : T = {
  runWithTimeout(timeout)(f).getOrElse(default)}`

```
val f = runWithTimeout(300){evalfunc(a, b)}
```

But it says, tools.Interval cannot be cast to scala.Option. How do I add a timer in this function? I need val `f` as `Interval(Int, Int)` and then I am doing some computation on `f`.

My problem is that I have tried using the solution given in the link. In my case, I am trying to add the timeout for a method which returns `Interval(Int, Int)` and it says it requires scala.Option.

Comment: I have already seen the answers of this link and mentioned that in my question. Please check the link in the question.

Comment: Just replace `Option[T]` with `T`, and remove the cast.

Comment: btw `.asInstanceOf` is generally a symptom of something going wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you casting it to `Option` in the first place? 
The [documentation for `Await.result`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/concurrent/Await$.html) states that the return type of `result[T]` is `T`, not `Option[T]`.

You could make an `Option[T]` out of it, but for this you would have to catch the `TimeoutException` that is thrown if the `result` method does not succeed within the specified time constraints.

Try something like this maybe:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

def runWithTimeout[T]
  (timeout: Long)
  (f: => T)
  (implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
: Option[T] = {
  try {
    Some(Await.result(Future(f), timeout.seconds))
  } catch {
    case e: TimeoutException => None
  }
}
```

Notice that all this time-out and waiting-stuff affects only the part of the program that is waiting. It does not affect the execution of your complicated numerical procedure `f` in any way: once it's started, it runs no matter what, and there is no way to stop it if it runs within the same JVM, because a JVM is not an operating system. If you want to be able to actually stop the execution of `f`, then you have two options:

- Make `f` cooperative, that is, it should occasionally check whether the result is still needed, and stop if the result is no longer needed because of the timeout.
- Run `f` as a separate process, outside of the JVM, kill it using the tools of the operating system after the timeout.

Comment: Thank you very much. It timed out, but yes I need to stop the execution of `f`. I will try to run it separately.